# How to insert multiple rows of data in SQL by python?

Tags: python, sql

I have connected python to sqlite3 and have an example table like this.

```
fruit   name
apple   
banana  
peach
```

I want to insert data into the second column.
I have tried

```
my_list = [("John",), ("Jack",), ("Joe",),]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO fruit_table (name) VALUES (?)", my_list)
```

But the results is like this

```
fruit   name
apple   None
banana  None
peach   None
None    John
None    Jack
None    Joe
```

I have also tried

```
cursor.excutemany("UPDATE fruit_table SET name = (?)", my_list)
```

But the result is like

```
fruit   name
apple   Joe
banana  Joe
peach   Joe
```

It seems it only take the last name in the list in each column.

What I expect is

```
fruit   name
apple   John
banana  Jack
peach   Joe
```

Comment: Without a `where` clause the update will effect every row. Every row is assigned to every name in order, and only the last name in the list remains

Comment: In the real data, I have thousnads rows so is there any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Note that columns in SQL have no order so you need to be careful to assign the correct fruit to every name. This assumes names are sorted alphabetically by fruit:

```py
names = [
        'bob',
        'charlie',
        'felix'
]

# Change this order by if the names are in a different order
result = cursor.execute('SELECT fruit FROM fruits ORDER BY fruit').fetchall()
cursor.executemany(
    'UPDATE fruits SET name=(?) WHERE fruit=(?)',
    zip(names, (i[0] for i in result)) # Generator needed since cursors return a tuple
)

cursor.execute('SELECT * from fruits')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```